# Opensips avp_db_query can't compare null value

Tags: database, voip, opensips

I am using avp_db_query to retrieve my table row, sometimes one field value is null. But when I use if condition it does not follow and move on.

```
avp_db_query("select status from orders where id = 1", "$avp(status);")
```

Now if i write condition

```
if($avp(status)==1){
   do success
 } else {
   do failure
   exit();
 }
```

Above condition does not work on failure status and continue, but when I put two if conditions and check if it is equal to one or equal to 0 then it works.

another issue is if this column has null value than nothing work, and it proceeds with giving the following warning.

```
WARNING:core:comp_scriptvar: invalid EQUAL operation: left is 
VARIABLE_ELEMENT/STRING_VAL, right is NUMBER/NO_VAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for `NULL` SQL column values with:

```
if ($avp(status) == "<null>")
```

... which is equivalent to:

```
if ($(avp(status)[0]) == "<null>")
```

It was the only way we could get this to work, given that the `$avp(status) = NULL;` statement is meant to delete the top-most value in the AVP's stack.

If you are claiming that the `else` statement is not executed when it should be, please give a [minimally viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with the output of `opensips -V`, possibly opening up a new [issue](https://github.com/OpenSIPS/opensips/issues), separately.

Comment: Thanks, well will put another post for if condition and else if.